# Jdbc and MySql not wanting to play nicely together

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java

I have been working on a java application that has a connection to a mysql database. I can connect and run queries but when I try to take a string and run it as a sql query I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO usageData (`COMID`,`Year`,`Month`,`kwhr`,`co2`) 
VALUES ('15650', '2' at line 3
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1583)
```

Bellow is the code that I'm using to connect to the database

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String dbms = "mysql";
    String serverName = "localhost";
    String portNumber = "8889";
    String DBName = "ConnectDatabase";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";

    ArrayList<Integer> yearList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<CustomerRecord> customerRecordList = getCustomerRecords(args[0], yearList);
    ArrayList<ClimateRecord> climateRecordList = getClimateRecords(args[1]);


    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    for (CustomerRecord record : customerRecordList) {
        buf.append(customerRecord2SQL(record));
    }

    for (int i = (climateRecordList.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        //for (ClimateRecord record : climateRecordList) {
        ClimateRecord record = climateRecordList.get(i);
        buf.append(climateRecord2SQL(record));
    }

    buf.append(cityStats(dbms,serverName,portNumber,DBName,user,password));
    buf.append(zipStats(dbms,serverName,portNumber,DBName,user,password));

    System.out.println(buf.toString());

    //here is the code to go ahead and update the database
    Connection con = null;

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + dbms + "://" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + "/" + DBName + "?user="+user+"&password=" + password);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate(buf.toString());

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[2]));
    out.write(buf.toString());
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: What does this statement: `System.out.println(buf.toString());` print exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  not a connection issue. It means that something is wrong with your SQL statement. Try copying the statement as is and executing it directly in the database. See what is wrong and then correct it in the Java code.

I notice that the single quotes around the field names look fancy. That might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion any ordinarily I would say you are right however. I do have it print out the entire query and I ran it through phpMyAdmin with no problems.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it is the same SQL statement? What datatype is COMID and year and so on? I notice you quoted the values. Also why the fancy quotes for the fieldnames?

Comment: Yeah I'm absolutely sure it's the same statement. I tried doing something simple just Truncating a table. It always throws the same error on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what was happening and what everyone else failed to realize. JDBC will not do more than one query at a time I was trying to run several million queries contained in a string buffer which wouldn't work.

Comment: Huh? From your original question, how were we supposed to guess that that's what you were doing?

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be 'INSERT INTO usageData `VALUES` (`COMID`,`Year`,`Month`,`kwhr`,`co2`); 
and btw COMID,year...what are these..?? and why fancy quotes...??

Comment: That's not correct. It looks like you've mixed up column names with values.